# Find index of combobox item, when the item is a class

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I tried the `FindStringExact`, but it doesn't work...

I have a class:

```
public class ModelLangPS {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a combobox:

```
Dictionary<string, ModelLangPS> list = new Dictionary<string, ModelLangPS>();
foreach(JObject o in value) {
    list.Add(o["@id"].ToString(), new ModelLangPS() {
        Id   = o["@id"].ToString(),
        Name = "some string"
    });
}
comboBxJezik.DataSource = list.Values.ToList();
comboBxJezik.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBxJezik.ValueMember = "id";
comboBxJezik.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

When I get the `id` of the Language, I want to set the combobox item with that `id`.

Something like:

```
string langID = "5";
comboBxJezik.SelectedIndex = ???;
```

If anyone could help me, I would be grateful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need a index? Just use `SelectedValue` property;

```
comboBxJezik.SelectedValue = langID;
```

Comment: Although accepted as an answer - this doesn't actually answer the question (but maybe the OPs problem).

Comment: @Charemer Sometimes questions are XY questions. User needs X, but he thinks Y is the solution and asks how to do Y rather than X. I see this is one of that kind of question. User has a value in hand, why do you think he needs to use SelectedIndex?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel  Part of the point of stackexchange is to find answers that match the questions.  While the accepted answer is OK for the OP it doesn't actually answer the question (perhaps the question should be corrected to match the accepted answer)  Searching this question - my situation is such that the accepted answer can't solve my problem. As in my case the question is correct as stated.

Answer (score 2):

Findstringexact looks at the item's display member only. You could do this:

```
combo.SelectedItem = list.Values.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Id == id);
```

Or this

```
combo.SelectedItem = list[id];
```

Comment: The first solution also works perfectly, tnx for the idea! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think that can work:

```
comboBxJezik.SelectedItem = list[langID].Name;
```